# Apache reverse proxy rules to create HTTP headers from URI information?

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

I am testing a web application that is hosted in production behind [SiteMinder](http://www.ca.com/us/secure-sso.aspx), which authenticates the user and adds an HTTP header to each request that identifies that user.

The application does not work if the header is not present and I am trying to test it using [Watir and Webdriver](http://watirwebdriver.com/). This combination drives a real browser (e.g. Firefox) locally so I am not able to insert HTTP headers easily via WebDriver. Our local test environment does not have SiteMinder so I need a way to insert the headers.

I have set up Apache 2 as a reverse proxy and want to translate a request like:

```
GET /SM_USER=fred@company.com/application/index.html
```

into:

```
GET /application/index.html
SM_USER: fred@company.com
```

Our servers are all Solaris 10 and I am currently using Apache/2.0.63 as installed with the OS (we are not using it for anything else).

The closest I have got is to use `SetEnvIf` and `mod_rewrite`:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "SM_USER=([^/]+)" HTTP_SM_USER=$1
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/.+(/application/.+)$ http://apphost:9090$1 [P]
```

But the header is not being set. It appears that the value of `Request_URI` is being rewritten *before* the `SetEnvIf` directive is being executed, so `SM_USER` is no longer in the URI.

If I am right about this, is it possible to change the order of execution so `SetEnvIf` gets the original URI? Or do I need a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague came up with a solution. I had made the mistake of assuming that using `SetEnvIf` by itself was sufficient. This is now working for us:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Anything ending with /application/.+ goes to http://apphost:9090
RewriteRule ^/.+(/application/.+)$ http://apphost:9090$1 [P]
# Match SM_USER= in the URI and set an env var with its value.
SetEnvIf Request_URI "SM_USER=([^/]+)" SM_USER=$1
# If the env var is set, put the value into a request header.
RequestHeader set SM_USER "%{SM_USER}e" env=SM_USER
```

This URI is proxied to `http://apphost:9090/application/index.html` with the HTTP header `SM_USER` set to `fred@company.com`:

```
/SM_USER=fred@company.com/application/index.html
```

Comment: As someone who likes using Apache reverse proxy regularly, I appreciate the question & answer here. Very helpful.